# GWT CellTree scroll to arbitrary node

Tags: gwt

i'm coding some kind of objects browser, organized with folders. When user seslects some folder in the list i have to expand an appropriate node in a tree. 
I've implemented tree expand, element selection in tree, BUT expand might happen at a part of tree that is out of visible area (CellTree is on a ScrollPane). 
So, i do have an instace of `TreeNode` - how can i programmatically scroll to make it visible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible with the current API, but what you can try, and I haven't tested this, but should be easy:

1. For each object in your tree render and invisible tag, identifying this object, like an `<input type="hidden" id="yourObjectId"/>`
2. Make sure you have a `SelectionModel` when setting up your NodeInfo etc.
3. When you know what object you want to scroll to, call `yourSelectionModel.setSelected(object,true);`. That should expand the tree and display your selected object.
4. At this stage what you want to do is:

> ```
> Element cellTreeElement = yourCellTree.getElement();
> NodeList<Element> objectIds = cellTreeElement.getElementsByTagName("input");
> for ( int i=0;i<elementsByTagName.getLength();i++ )
> {
>    Element e = objectIds .getItem( i );
>    if (e.getId().equals( yourObjectId ) {
>      e.scrollIntoView();
>    }
> }
> ```

Pretty sure this should work just fine.

Comment: some remarks: 
it's better to scroll to some visible element, otherwise scroll (in my  case) goes to the top of the cell (i add marked element inside render() of the cell). But maybe i have to move this element a bit down to bottom using styles.

and regarding point 3 - it's not enough to call 'setSelected' - instead i had to find all objects in the path to selected element using my datamodel and then traverse tree using 
'tree.getRootTreeNode' and 'rootNode.setChildOpen(...)'. Trick was that 'rootNode.setChildOpen(...)' returns opened child as a 'TreeNode'. 

thanks really much again!

Answer (score 0):

another version (if you want to move the element to the top of the CellTree):

```
    Element cellTreeElement = yourCellTree.getElement();
    NodeList<Element> objectIds = cellTreeElement.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (int j = 0; j < objectIds.getLength(); j++) {
        Element e = objectIds.getItem(j);
        if (e.getId().equals("r" + iDistrictID)) {
            yourCellTree.getElement().getParentElement().getParentElement().setScrollTop(e.getParentElement().getParentElement().getOffsetTop());
        }
    }
```