# How to Get Pixel Offset of GWT Tree Node?

Tags: java, user-interface, gwt

I was wondering if is possible to get the pixel offset of a given `TreeNode` in GWT's `CellTree`. I have scoured the documentation and found that only the class [`CellTreeNodeView`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/CellTreeNodeView.html) inherits from UiObject and hence has the pixel offset directly available. Yet this class is only used internally and all methods used to access it are package private.

I am trying implement a way to programmatically scroll to the position of the selected node; so far the only way that has worked for me is to calculate (using an in-order traversal algorithm) the number of nodes above it and multiply that by the render size of the nodes. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [GWT CellTree scroll to arbitrary node](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980026/gwt-celltree-scroll-to-arbitrary-node)

Comment: I saw that post; my issue, though, is that I have to be able to scroll within a widget using `ScrollPanel` while DOM events, to my knowledge, can only scroll the whole page.

Comment: My bad. I've retracted the close vote.